# Why is a question about Linux driver APIs off topic?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This morning I asked what Linux kernel driver API applies to a simple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535150/what-linux-driver-subsystem-api-is-used-for-a-simple-screen-monitor-device). Six hours later it has been closed as "off-topic" with no explanation. Would someone mind explaining how this is off-topic, and perhaps which Stack Exchange network would be more appropriate?

Comment: Why a [php], [sql] and [html] programmer close a kernel question has no easy explanation.  It does tend to mean "I don't know so you shouldn't know either" too often these days.

Comment: @HansPassant: You know, never assume malice in the first place ;) The question contains the sentence: _"What subsystem/API should I use?"_ I guess the close voters just did some keyword spotting and interpreted the question as recommendation request.

Comment: Hmm, assuming stupidity hardly puts a more positive spin on it.  You live in [c++] land, you see this happening every day.  Embellished with long comment trails from users that insist on testifying why they don't have to know the answer.

Comment: I was ready to blame the [driver] tag. Now if only I can actually find an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was closed by 3 users for the following sub-category of off-topic:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Why Stack Overflow has started suppressing that detailed description with the new post notices (and *only* that sub-category of “off-topic”) is entirely beyond my comprehension. That is what created this confusion. (Well, that and the larger problem of forcing these nuanced, SO-specific close reasons into a category named “off-topic”, and therefore implying the question is not about programming.)

At any rate, I believe the closure was in error. You were not asking for assistance locating an off-site resource, like a website, manual, or tutorial. You were asking about an appropriate API to solve a problem that you described. That is entirely on-topic. As such, I’ve reopened the question.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I can't say I'm all that happy though. With the question open again I now feel like I've won a battle that shouldn't have been necessary; justifying the existence of my question. Linux kernel programmers are few enough that my question already had a low chance of finding useful answer *before* this whole debacle pushed it outside the "interesting" (new) category. My opinion of SO has been sliding downhill for a while now, but this experience definitely represents a milestone in said descent.

Comment: @memtha Be careful not to blow this out of proportion. Having a question closed incorrectly is not a "battle". Mistakes happen.

Comment: The battle wasn't having it closed, it was getting it reopened. Compare the experience I've had here: erroneously closed, seek mod intervention, reopened,  post bounty, 4 edits, argument in comments over terminology, no answer - with my experience with [the same question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_programming/comments/eis2rn/what_linux_driversubsystemapi_is_used_for_a/): 4 answers of varying usefulness and a meaningful discussion. (Note: I encouraged the auther of the accepted reddit answer to post the same answer here to get the bounty.) Reddit has proven more friendly then SO.